# Fix capitalization of Emacs

Tags: feature-request, bug

When I ask to close a question because it's not really about Emacs, the radio-button for that says:

> This question does not appear to be about emacs, within the scope defined in the help center.

Could we change this so it says "Emacs" (which is the actual name of our beloved program) instead of "emacs" (which is merely the name of its executable)?